# Aptana 3.6.0 jre Error in Windows os

Tags: aptana, aptana3

i used Aptana 3.4.2 and its run well.
when i download 3.6.0(Current version) and install it i get this Error:

```
---------------------------
Aptana Studio 3
---------------------------
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Xverify:none
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Program Files (x86)\AptanaStudio\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher C:\Program Files (x86)\Aptana Studio\AptanaStudio3.exe
-name Aptana Studio 3
--launcher.library C:\Program Files (x86)\AptanaStudio\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup C:\Program Files (x86)\Aptana Studio\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 2f90_7c
-vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Xverify:none
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Program Files (x86)\Aptana Studio\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

and ini file is(AptanaStudio3.ini):

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-name
Aptana Studio 3
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Xverify:none
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

my jre path is:
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20

i add this line

```
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin\javaw.exe
```

into AptanaStudio3.ini 
but not fix!

Comment: i also change java var in environment Variable but not fix!!

Comment: What's interesting is that no one knows?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install the 32-bit java as well and that should clear your issue. Although its x64 compatible it does not like to find the x64 Java. Even if you link it to your correct java you get the ini error. Weird but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Prefix the system `PATH` variable in the `studio3.bat` file with the JRE 32bit path and launch the program using the batch file.

```
set PATH=%PRGF86%\Java\jre1.8.0_25;%PRGF86%\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin;%PATH%;
```

That way you won't interfere with your other 64 applications.

To pin the batch file to the taskbar, create a short cut for the file and add `cmd.exe /C`  at the beginning of its target properties.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue: You should install jdk 1.8. Then look for the aptanaStudio3.ini file (C:\Users\yourName\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio), open the file (text-editor) and insert these two lines:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\javaw.exe
```

before vmargs in the .ini file. (this is important if you place at the beginning or end, it will not work)

See my complete AptanaStudio3.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```